# Python subprocess slower when python is executed from VBA

Tags: python, vba, ms-word

**Here is VBA**

```
Sub patseersearchPats1()
    pyfile = "path/to/test.py"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    ccmd = "python" & " " & pyfile & " " & """" & Selection.Range.Text & """"
    objShell.Run ccmd, 0, False
End Sub
```

**here is python**

```
import subprocess
import os
import uuid
import sys
import time

appdata = os.getenv('APPDATA')
npp = os.path.join(appdata, r"npp.7\notepad++.exe") #path to minimalistic npp 7

def MsgBox(data):
    temp = os.path.join(appdata, str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.md')
    with open(temp, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(data + '\n')

    subprocess.call([npp, temp])
    time.sleep(1)
    os.remove(temp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MsgBox(sys.argv[1])
```

Python script when ran from cmd like this.
`c:\test>python pyfile.py "string"`
opens in flash, but using it from VBA takes lot of time.

**tests:**

directly running python:

less than one second.

from VBA

15-20 seconds.

so I think this is not a performance issue but a procedural issue.

Comment: Maybe more a question for code review?

Comment: hmm. lets wait.

Comment: If you care about performance why are you using VBA and python?

Comment: You are right. Python part is ok. I think problem is with VBA part and there is not any viable alternative when you are working with Microsoft word.